# Get id items of the array and push them to a new one

Tags: php

I've got an

```
$array = array(1,22,54,75,90,364)
```

How is it posaible to create a new array of it's id items?

```
$newarray = $array[i];
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the function `array_flip()`.

Comment: Like this? https://3v4l.org/E1bsW better version

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply use `array_keys()`

```
$newarray = array_keys($array);
```